# Multiple subselect joins to the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Background

I have a Postgres database of shows (show_id int, title string) and episodes (show_id int, ep_id int, title string, date int).

I want to issue a query that returns all shows with their titles, their episode count (= number of episodes with their id as the show_id), next episode title, and next episode airtime. The times are Unix timestamps and the next episode is obviously `min(date) where date > now`. If a show has no upcoming episodes, those fields are null.

## Schema Example

shows:

```
show_id | title
--------|-------
1       | The X-Files
2       | Fringe
3       | Seinfeld
```

episodes:

```
ep_id | title             | date      | show_id
------|-------------------|-----------|---------
1     | Mulder's Holiday  | 110876621 | 1
2     | Walt Retires      | 128101332 | 2
3     | Kramer & Dracula  | 184220112 | 3
4     | Scully's Tattoo   | 100298110 | 1
5     | Skinner in Hawaii | 218101310 | 1
```

## Desired result set

```
show_title  | episode_count | next_episode      | next_airing
------------|---------------|-------------------|-----------
The X-Files | 221           | Skinner in Hawaii | 218101310
Seinfeld    | 167           | NULL              | NULL
```

## What I've tried

```
select title, c.count, d.next_episode, d.next_airing
from shows s
inner join (select show_id, count(*)
            from episodes
            group by show_id) c
inner join (select show_id, title next_next_episode, date next_airing
            from episodes
            group by show_id) d
on c.show_id = s.show_id
on d.show_id = s.show_id
```

The first inner join works, to select episode counts, but duplicating it to select the next episode title and date doesn't. The problem seems to be that inner joins on subselects only work if what you're selecting is part of an aggregate function? Or something along those lines -- my book doesn't cover this, and I found it hard to figure out on my own, after spending half my evening on Google. If anyone could offer a tip about how to do this I'd really be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

In the second inner join you should use distiinct and not group by  ..  do the fact you have  not aggregation function

```
select s.title, c.count, d.next_episode, d.next_airing
from shows s
inner join (select show_id, count(*)
            from episodes
            group by show_id) on c.show_id = s.show_id
inner join (select distinct show_id, title next_next_episode, date next_airing
            from episodes
            ) d on d.show_id = s.show_id
```

I have arrange the query using JOIN ON SQL format  .. hope this is not agaisnt you db code rules

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky.  First, you need a filter for the dates.  Second, you need outer joins, in case there is no next episode.  Try this version:

```
select s.show_id, e.episode_count, enext.title, enext.date
from shows s left join
     (select show_id, count(*) as episode_count
      from episodes e
      group by show_id
     ) e left join
     (select distinct on (ep_id) e.*
      from episodes e
      where date > extract(epoch from now())
      order by ep_id, date
     ) enext
     on enext.show_id = s.show_id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a syntax error, and I can't figure why or where.

Comment: @GreenTriangle . . . For some reasons I put the MySQL function for the unix timestamp in instead of the Postgres expression.